# Selecting Distinct Using SQLite package in R

Tags: mysql, r, sqlite

I've been charged with finding how many telecasts does each series have?

I have the following tables from which to choose from:

[image]

So far I've gotten the following:

```
sql <- "select series_name, sum(telecast_id) from telecast group by 
series_name limit 10"
res <- dbSendQuery(con, sql)
df_tc <- dbFetch(res)
print(df_tc)
```

It returns too many values though.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a one-question-at-a-time kind of place

Comment: The `sum` doesnt seem correct. Do you want `count`?

Comment: Yes Count would be what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum` returns the total of the values in the brackets. So you're adding up the telecast IDs and getting large values. To determine "how many", as in "how many records", you need to use `count()`. If you assume that no record has a NULL telecast ID, then leave the column name blank inside the brackets. I've also named the result ("As n") but that's optional. And why limit the top 10? That was not specified in the question, so delete it.

```
sql <- "Select series_name, count() As n from telecast group by series_name"
```

The other commands seem ok.